# Does order of linker flags matter when running linking step in C++?

Tags: linker, makefile, eclipse-cdt

My original question is below, but it evolved to the following related question: **is there anything wrong with putting linker flags after the objects in the linker statement?**

---

When I build in Eclipse, the following linking statement is run:

`g++ -fopenmp -lconfig++ -o "pc2"  ./main.o ./sampling.o ./simulation.o`

which is incorrect, because `lconfig++` must follow, not precede, the object file listing.  So, I modified the makefile, which was automatically generated by Eclipse based on the project settings.  Specifically, I changed this portion of the makefile

```
# Tool invocations
pc2: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)
    @echo 'Building target: $@'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C++ Linker'
    g++ -fopenmp -lconfig++ -o "pc2" $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS)
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '
```

to be as follows:

```
# Tool invocations
pc2: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)
    @echo 'Building target: $@'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C++ Linker'
    g++ -o "pc2" $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS) -fopenmp -lconfig++ 
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '
```

Then, after modifying that 1 line of the makefile, I entered

`make clean all -C release`

at the command line, which produced the following correct linking statement:

`g++ -o "pc2"  ./main.o ./sampling.o ./simulation.o -fopenmp -lconfig++`

Therefore, I *know* how to fix the makefile so that the build process is correct.

What I do *not* know is how to configure Eclipse so that the makefile it generates places the linker flags (or "options"?) at the correct location.

Comment: After posting this question, I discovered that I could move `${FLAGS}` in settings > linker > "command line pattern" to the end of the pattern specification.  This fixed the problem.  However, it raises the question: is there any reason why I might need linker flags to precede the object files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've answered your own question: yes, the order of objects and libraries on the link line [does matter](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html).

> is there any reason why I might need linker flags to precede the object files?

There may *well* exist such linker flags. For example `--start-group` GNU-ld linker options must (obviously) precede the library group it starts.  The `--start-lib` Gold linker option must (obviously) precede the objects that form a library, etc.

> I discovered that I could move ${FLAGS} in settings

You likely have included `-lconfig++` in the `${FLAGS}` somewhere in Eclipse, and that's likely a mistake -- the `-lconfig++` is *not* a linker flag (even though it looks like one), it's a library specification, and should probably be included in `${LIBS}` or some such.